# Drawing on JPanel with JButton, JSpinner, etc

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So i am trying to make a graphical interface for school, which involves a JMenuBar, JSpinner, and 2 JButtons. Below these objects I'm trying to draw a simple rectangle. I've already tried using the paintComponent method in the class which extends JPanel but it stil doesn't appear.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class A1 {

public final static int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 640;
public final static int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = DEFAULT_WIDTH /12*9;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("A1");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT));
    frame.requestFocus();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    lePanel panel = new lePanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setJMenuBar(panel.getMenuBar());

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class lePanel extends JPanel {

JMenuBar menuBar;
JButton submit;
JButton check;
JSpinner spinner;

public String test;

public lePanel() {
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(createFileMenu(new JMenu("File")));
    menuBar.add(createHelpMenu(new JMenu("Help")));

    spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 10, 1));
    add(spinner);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    add(submit);

    check = new JButton("Check");
    add(check);

    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == submit)
            {
                test = spinner.getValue().toString();
                System.out.println("Spinner Submitted");
            }
        }

    });

    check.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == check)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(lePanel.this, test, "Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    });
}

private JMenu createHelpMenu(JMenu jMenu) {
    JMenu menu = jMenu;
    JMenuItem helpItem = new JMenuItem("Help");
    menu.add(helpItem);
    return menu;
}

private JMenu createFileMenu(JMenu jMenu) {
    JMenu menu = jMenu;
    JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New");
    JMenuItem clearItem = new JMenuItem("Clear");
    JMenuItem chooseFileItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });

    menu.add(newItem);
    menu.add(clearItem);
    menu.add(chooseFileItem);
    menu.add(saveItem);
    menu.add(exitItem);
    return menu;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.drawRect(200, 200, 50, 50);
}

public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
    return menuBar;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

By doing this, your lePanel JPanel sizes to its preferred size, a size much too small to show the rectangle. Delete this line and your JFrame's contentPane will use its default BorderLayout, and the drawing JPanel will fill the lower part of your GUI, as per the BordrLayout rules, and you'll see the drawing.

Note a useful debugging technique is to add a border around a component of interest to see where it is and how big it is. For example, I placed this in your lepanel constructor

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("le panel"));
```

and it visually showed me your problem.

---

Other unrelated issues:

- You will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.
- Remember to use the `@Override` annotation above any methods that you think might be overriding another, such as your `paintComponent` method. This will allow the compiler to notify you if you are in fact overriding things incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated :D